# Writing startup script for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, upstart, startupscript

**Note**: I did consider putting this question on the [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) site, but believe it is a scripting/programming question at its core, and thus deserves to be here on SO.

I'm trying to use [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) to run a script every time I turn my Ubuntu desktop on. Specifically, I want to ping my router every 30 seconds (for reasons outside the scope of this question).

I read the [upstart tutorial](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) and also read up on a few example articles from around the internet. I am planning on writing and saving the script to a file called `/etc/init/heartbeat.conf`, which I *believe* is the correct location and file extension for upstart scripts (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Here is the contents of that script (which I have hacked together from various tutorials/examples online):

```
start on started network-manager
script
    ping -i 30 192.168.1.1 | cat >> ~/heartbeat/ping.log
end script
```

When I start my machine, I don't get any GUI/gnome-related errors, and don't see anything in `/var/log/syslog`, but I also don't see any `ping` output in `~/heartbeat/ping.log`. Where am I going astray? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need the solution to be specifically an `upstart` script (e.g would `cron` be a solution)?

Comment: Hi @VilhelmGray - yes I am looking specifically for an `upstart` solution here - thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The location of the upstart script `/etc/init.d/heartbeat.conf` is correct, but there are few other issues with the script:

- Recommended way to start the script is:

  `start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo`

  This will ignore the `lo` (loopback) interface, and will also ensure that filesystems are mounted before the script runs (since you are writing to a file)
- You have given path as `~/heartbeat/ping.log`. But the script will run as `root` user, not your user! So checking in your home folder won't work. Also generally, upstart scripts don't honor `~` as you would expect. So always use a full path
- If a folder called `heartbeat` doesn't exist, then the ping command itself would throw an error, saying `~/heartbeat: no such file or directory`. The directory *must* exist in order for the redirection to succeed

Here is the updated script:

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo
stop on runlevel [016]
script
  ping -i 30 192.168.1.1 >> /full/path/to/ping.log 2>&1
end script
```

Optional items:

- Do you really need a `| cat` in the original ping command?
- Check `/var/log/upstart/heartbeat.log` for the actual upstart logs. If the `script` section itself did not succeed, then the error messages would be present in this log file.

Edit: Typo, start better, redirect error also to log file

Comment: This is a very gentle answer. Congrats!